# What is the alternative of shared drive?

Tags: file-management, cloud-storage

There is a MS windows server, where files are kept and accessed in shared drive manner. Type of the files includes MS Word (.doc,.docx), MS excel(.xls, .xlsx), images (.jpeg), text files(.txt) and PDF. 
This doesn't seem to be a good way to keep and maintain files where multiple users have access to.
Looking for a secured tool which will serve the below purposes:

1. To keep files secured and access restricted
2. To manage(edit/ copy/ cut) files easily
3. To give/ take away access permission easily to anyone within the organisation

Comment: Windows already lets you do all of this.

Comment: You need to  create some directories for those user and then use the Windows File System permissions system to assign each users read/write/list/execute in their assigned directory and take away all other user's permission to read/write/list/execute on other users' directories. That's a very basic explanation. You're going to need to review the basic windows file permissions/ACL system docs to learn it.

Comment: A shared drive really is about the only option Windows gives you.  MS is very good at vendor lock-in.  You can easily do all the things you're talking about on a shared drive though.